# Devo pedir a senha do usuário duas vezes no momento do cadastro?

Tags: segurança, ux, senhas

Nos formulários de cadastro, é comum ver o campo "Digite sua senha novamente", como uma confirmação para ter certeza de que o usuário não errou a senha digitada.

Pensando na experiência do usuário, esse campo é realmente necessário? Pensando nas [heurísticas de Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/), pra esse caso, não existe uma convergência entre "prevenção de erros" (heurística 5) e "estética e design minimalista" (heurística 8)?

Como aplicar a heurística de prevenção de erro nesse caso? Não seria um botão de "esqueci minha senha" no caso do usuário ter digitado errado? Ou seria mesmo o campo de "digite sua senha novamente"? E por que?

Essa etapa de confirmação adiciona algum fator de segurança para o fluxo? Novamente em segurança, se meu formulário tiver esse campo, eu deveria estar fazendo essa confirmação no lado do cliente, no lado do servidor, ou em ambos?

Note que não procuro opiniões sobre o assunto, mas respostas concretas, com fontes confiáveis, e bem embasadas em termos de UX.

Comment: Particularmente, creio que um campo com o "olho" para revelar a senha já serviria como uma confirmação. Mas e se o usuário estiver com alguém do lado e não puder clicar ali? Não é um assunto tão simples quanto parece, envolve muitas variáveis.

Comment: O propósito é evitar definir uma senha que foi digitada errado por engano, me parece uma boa prática de segurança, pense em quantos problema de "perdi minha senha", ou mesmo "digitei meu email errado" (sim, para aqueles casos que tens de confirmar tbm o email), é um protocolo de confirmação perfeitamente aceitável

Comment: @RafaelTavares, o que impede o "usuário do lado" olhar o cara digitando a senha? Acaba dando na mesma... :-]

Comment: @LuizFelipe se for no celular, pode dar na mesma, se for no computador / notebook, não. Vai depender da velocidade que a pessoa digita, quantos dedos ela usa ao digitar, a mão estar na frente das teclas etc. Fora que se alguém estiver sentado atrás de mim por um motivo X aceitável, ela pode não conseguir me ver digitando mas conseguir ver a tela. Enfim, muitas variáveis, não é algo tão simples. Já participei de uma palestra onde o apresentador digitou uma senha com o tablet conectado no projetor e todos puderam ver o que ele digitava mesmo com o campo *****, são diferentes situações.

Comment: A maioria das pessoas digita com os indicadores e lentamente :D, ainda mais com a decadência do uso de computadores em detrimento de celulares. Mas eu concordo com você, é algo bem complexo de ser resolvido. Eu pessoalmente _prefiro_ colocar o segundo campo de confirmação, mas não tenho nenhum embasamento na perspectiva de UX para isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toda resposta sobre UX tem que começar com aquele blablablá de que você tem que conduzir estudos, analisar seu público, etc.

Feito isso e para dar um parâmetro eu vou recorrer ao UX.SE que é um dos lugares onde mais tem pessoas especializadas no assunto e [lá vi algumas respostas](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/20953/1490).

A conclusão majoritária é que não deve pedir. Mas tenho medo de ser uma percepção apenas porque foi a resposta aceita e por causa disso ela recebeu muitos votos.

Um dos motivos apresentados é que as pessoas burlam isso e acabam copiando automaticamente, então o mecanismo pode não funcionar porque a pessoa "digita" errado nas duas e ainda cria uma dificuldade para a pessoa que é desnecessária.

O que recomenda-se é ter outras formas de resolver o problema caso a pessoa não lembre a senha ou tenha digitado ela errado e não está funcionando. De um jeito ou de outro você precisa ter esse mecanismo, então deixe só ele.

A ideia é que é mais usável quando você só crie um fardo para a pessoa se ele cometeu mesmo um erro e está tendo problemas por isso. O sistema de recuperação de senha (que não devolve a senha mas deixa você trocar) é mais efetivo. Você paga só se precisar. Quando você pede para a pessoa digitar duas vezes você paga mesmo fazendo tudo certo, e pode ter que pagar de novo depois.

Note que não é unânime, algumas pessoas apresentam problemas dessa abordagem, então tem que ser bem pensado.

Um dos problemas que disseram é que a pessoa pode estar com o CAPS LOCK ligado, mas você deveria detectar isso e avisar a pessoa antes de digitar. UX é pensar em resolver cada problema com a ação certa, somos engenheiros até fazendo UX. Engenheiro acha a melhor solução para cada problema, não segue receita de bolo.

Também reclamaram que teria que deixar a senha visível para a pessoa conferir, mas isso não deve ser feito, deve ter a opção de tornar visível em dado momento e aí a pessoa escolhe fazê-lo se ela se certificou que ninguém está vendo ou ela não liga para isso.

Não adianta forçar as pessoas fazerem algo que elas não querem, elas darão um jeito de fazer errado se o errado for melhor para ela.

[image: Diferença entre o caminho que desenharam e o que as pessoas usam]

Algo que é recomendado até para confirmar o e-mail é a pessoa precisar clicar no *link* enviado para confirmar que o e-mail está certo e que não é um uso indevido de um endereço. Tem várias formas de lidar com isso. É uma boa ideia.

Um problema que existe mesmo é que a pessoa pode não perceber que errou e não saber depois o que fazer, e o seu site não ter nenhum indicativo disso, você poderia perder o usuário. É algo para se pensar. Realmente acontece em alguns cenários. Por isso não tem solução mágica universal que funciona sempre e está livre de problemas.

Um  argumento interessante para usar esse mecanismo é que ele é tão amplamente usado que as pessoas já não se importam mais. O que acha? Eu sei que as pessoas odeiam esses processos de *sign up*.

Uma solução pode ser usar um autenticador externo e evitar isso. Tem seus problemas, não deve ser a única forma, mas mata sua dúvida para a maioria dos casos.

## Segurança

Outra solução que obviamente tem seus defeitos é não pedir senha para a pessoa digitar. Resolve outros problemas de segurança. Gere uma para ele, é essa que ele deve usar. Ele que use um gerenciador, anote no caderninho ou peça a "recuperação" toda vez que for entrar, o que é quase um *two factor authentication*, exceto que ele esqueceu um dos fatores :D, mas esse é um mecanismo mais forte do que só saber a senha.

Não ache que é mais seguro pedir a senha duas vezes, pode ser mais confiável que a pessoa digitou certo, mas não 100% confiável, muito menos seguro.

O que pode acontecer quando você pede uma digitação apenas e deixa a pessoa ver é que talvez ela digite mais facilmente senhas mais longas e difíceis. Quando você cria dificuldade para ela digitar algo ela tenderá digitar coisas menores e mais simples, e isso pode afetar a segurança em algum grau. Novamente, a pessoa burlará sua "proteção".

## Acessibilidade

Não vi ninguém em lugar algum que eu pesquisei discutindo esse aspecto. Curioso né?

Talvez pedir duas vezes ajude quem precisa de acessibilidade porque é, provavelmente, a única forma dela conferir se digitou certo de forma a não expor a senha (a outra seria a senha digitada ser falada, mas aí todo mundo perto pode escutar). Mas há casos e casos.

Então talvez deveria ser opcional digitar ou não.

## Concluindo

É fácil achar falácias em todas essas opiniões, até porque ela viu um problema, mas talvez ele não seja tão relevante assim.

Todos os casos apresentados lá têm seus problemas, escolha seu veneno. De fato essas regrinhas apresentadas na resposta tem algum grau de dicotomia, e talvez seja até proposital, você tem que escolher qual regra é mais importante. Só não descarte soluções criativas, até mesmo de adotar ambos de alguma forma opcional. Não estou dizendo que é bom, mas não siga uma receita única, experimente, crie!

Algumas coisas eu tenho meio claro o que costuma compensar mais, mas essa não. Talvez mude muito pouco, sem pensar em um público específico.

Alguns *links* para acompanhar mais discussões e artigos de gente que trabalha com isso:

- [UX Movement](https://uxmovement.com/forms/why-the-confirm-password-field-must-die/)
- [Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/password-creation/) (sua referência) - é mais amplo do que esse ponto, mas deve ajudar
- [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/484/1490) - gerou boas discussões nessa pergunta também
- [CLX](https://cxl.com/blog/password-ux/) - muita gente *high profile* falou lá

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).